# Error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list. How to solve?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I have written the following code in which I have initialise the vector with along with declaration of vector. Just like array but it is throwing the following error :-

CODE IS :-

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> v  = {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector <int> :: iterator it ;
    it = v.begin();

    cout<< (*it) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

THE OUTPUT I RECEIVED IIN TERMINAL IS:-

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air Iterators % cd "/Users/apple/Desktop/CODE/Iterators/" && g++ iteratorsBasics.cpp -o iterat
orsBasics && "/Users/apple/Desktop/CODE/Iterators/"iteratorsBasics
iteratorsBasics.cpp:8:18: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    vector <int> v  = {1,2,3,4,5};
                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air Iterators %
```

Being the beginner I don't know how to sort this out please help.

the c++ version I checked in terminal by sawing some videos over internet is as follows:-

```
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code as it is, don't provide images of the code as (obviously) we cannot copy code from an image.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://onlinegdb.com/mtfAG8hY_)

Comment: the code in link you share is running well . But in my Pc it is throwing the error that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling agains C++98 or C++03 standard versions. Add the flag `-std=c++11` (or later: `c++14`/`c++17`/`c++20`) to the compiler invocation and it should compile.

Before C++11 `std::initializer_list` and the `std::initializer_list` overload of the `std::vector` constructor did not exist.

Comment: as a beginner I not know how to do this could you explain it out please.

Comment: @DboyDhruvil You are calling `g++ iteratorsBasics.cpp -o iteratorsBasics` as the compiler invocation, but it should be e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 iteratorsBasics.cpp -o iterat
orsBasics`. Wherever you set up the compiler to be invoked, you need to add that flag. I am not really familiar with visual studio code, so I can't help you with that. If you search for "visual studio code std=c++11" or similar, I am sure that you will find some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling your code with the following compiler flag:

```
-std=c++11
```

So the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

into the CMakeList.txt if you use CMake

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to code runner extension settings, then scroll down till you see this executor map. Click on Edit in settings.json.
   [image: Click on Edit in settings.json]
2. Press cmd+f then search for code-runner.executorMap
   [image: Make changes at highlighted place only]
3. Then under `cpp`, write `-std=c++17` after `g++` as show in the `ss`.
4. Save it, and run you program.

Comment: FWIW: anything from c++11 up will work. But this is the default for up-to-date versions of g++ and vcpp, so just updating the compiler (if possible -- I've worked in places which impose compilers more than 10 years old) should be sufficient.